# How to define logarithms for base other than e?

Tags: math, scheme, racket, logarithm

I'm trying to define **log** in Scheme. For example if

```
(log (exp 1)) ;=> 1.0
```

Then, how could I write log<sub>5</sub>(25)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `log` function in scheme yields the natural logarithm (base e) of a number. In order to compute the logarithm of a different base, you simply divide the log<sub>e</sub> of a number by the log<sub>e</sub> of the desired base.

To define a log<sub>5</sub> function in Scheme:

```
(define (log5 x) (/ (log x) (log 5)))
```

Then `(log5 25)` will yield `2.0`

Comment: While this answer is correct it is obsolete, because since R7RS you can now use the second argument of `log` to specify the base (cf. [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75538632/2326961)).

Answer (score 1):

Specify the base with the second argument of the `log` procedure (cf. [*Revised<sup>7</sup> Report on the Algorithmic Language Scheme*](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf), p. 79):

> The log procedure now accepts a second argument specifying the logarithm base.

For instance

```lisp
> (log 8 2)
3.0
```

Comment: FYI, the two-argument `log` definition was added in R6RS. Maybe R7RS put this in the language changes section because R6RS neglected to list it as a language change.